# does anyone know how to install howl IDE

Tags: lua, ide

I'm trying to install howl but I've got absolutely zero idea what to do and their website is no help what so ever. Has anyone done this before and know what to do?

Comment: I used my Linux package manager, but if you can't do the same you may ask on this thread https://gitter.im/howl-editor/howl or maybe open an issue on the Github repository in order to update the Howl FAQ.